# Weird behavior when using \babelfont with two styles in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel

Consider these MWEs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelprovide[main,import]{thai}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% \babelfont[thai]{rm}[
%     Script=Thai,
%     UprightFont = *.otf,
%     BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
%     ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
%     BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
%     {Laksaman}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[thai]{sf}[
    Script=Thai,
    UprightFont = *.otf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
    {Laksaman}

\begin{document}
    ข้อความทดสอบ Test text.
    \textsf{ข้อความทดสอบ Test text.}
\end{document}
```

The following code produces expected result. (Correctly apply serif and sans-serif style)
[image]

However, when I changed the serif font of Thai to the same as sans-serif one (Laksaman), the product of this code is formatted **wrong.** (The last test text's style is serif, not sans-serif)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelprovide[main,import]{thai}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelfont[thai]{rm}[
    Script=Thai,
    UprightFont = *.otf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
    {Laksaman}
% \babelfont[thai]{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[thai]{sf}[
    Script=Thai,
    UprightFont = *.otf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
    {Laksaman}

\begin{document}
    ข้อความทดสอบ Test text.
    \textsf{ข้อความทดสอบ Test text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, could anyone explains to me what happened here? Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 2):

`Babel` attemps to guess the family from the font name. If there are two families or two fonts with the same name it gets confused. I have to investigate how to deal with these cases. A hackish workaround is to copy and rename the font files (eg, `Laksaman-Bold.otf` → `LaksamanSF-Bold.otf`) and use the Harfbuzz renderer (the default one raises a lua error):

```
\babelfont[thai]{sf}[
    Script=Thai,       % Very likely redundant
    Renderer=Harfbuzz,
    UprightFont = *.otf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
    {LaksamanSF}       % The new name
```

[image: babelfont-thai]

**Edit** [Part of the original answer follows, which was not correct.] There is, hovewer, a simple solution: set a diferent NFSS name in the following way:

```
\babelfont[thai]{sf}[
    Script=Thai,
    NFSSFamily=LaksamanSF,
    UprightFont = *.otf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic.otf]
    {Laksaman}
```

[image: babelfont-thai-bad]

Comment: Still, there is a problem with the first "Test text." that set in *sans-serif* style instead of *serif*. Even if explicitly set English font "`\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[english]{sf}{Latin Modern Sans}`" doesn't solve the problem. Is there any solution to this? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I didn't look carefully. I’ve edited the answer.

Comment: @JavierBezos Can you add a luaotfload issue for the Lua error you get?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I didn’t say the bug is in the `luaotfload` side . I have to investigate first, but I'm somewhat busy.

Comment: @JavierBezos You didn't, but I am convinced that there is a luaotfload error here. I'll add an issue myself then.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Before reporting a bug I like to be sure, but I promise next time I'll be more obedient .